# Using a nested list comprehension to create a matrix of random 0s and 1s

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I just started to learn how list comprehension returns work. I am stuck on a tricky exercise.

I'd like to return a list that contains `n` lists and those lists contain `n` random integers 0 or 1.

```py
from random import randint
def CreateGraph(n):
    return [R for i in range(n) R[L[i]=randint(0,1)]]
n=3
print(CreateGraph(n))
```

What I was hoping for is something like:

```
[[0,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]
```

since my `n` is 3.

Instead, I got invalid syntax pointing at `R[L[i]=randint(0,1)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

```
>>> n = 3
>>> n
3
>>> [[randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: You beat me by 50 seconds ;) Perhaps you can add some explanation and what were the redundant variables in the OP's approach

Comment: thanks and It actually worked , but for the sake of me getting it more , can you explain why something like :" return [R[randint(0, 1) for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)] " can't work ? the fact of putting the name of your list .

Comment: `_` is just a dummy variable here which replaces `i` because you are not using `i` anywhere in the code. All you want is to generate three random numbers three times. Think of it like this: you have to call 3 mobile numbers from your phone. You don't care whom you call. You just dial a random number once and press call. You don't care who answers. You do the same second time. Again, you don't care who answers. You do the same third time. And yet again, you don't care who answers. *Your not caring while dialing is analogous to the `_`*